# not enough space on the right side of a curly brace with schemata package

Tags: schemata

I want to write some text next to the curly braces but there is not enough space and I want an even margin on both sides of the document .

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, text={16.5cm, 25.2cm}, centering]{geometry}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{ClearSans}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setlength{\parskip}{1.2ex}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}


\usepackage{schemata}

\begin{document}

conjonctions

\vspace{24pt}

\schema[close]{si\\
même si\\
sauf si\\
excepté si \\
comme si\\
dans la mesure où\\
}{+ indicatif}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you replace `\usepackage[a4paper, text={16.5cm, 25.2cm}, centering]{geometry}` with`\usepackage[a4paper, right=5cm,left=2cm, centering]{geometry}`will solve your problem.